# Error in TypeReference in Kotlin Jackson Mapper

Tags: kotlin, jackson, kotlin-extension, jackson-modules

I've got the following data class

```
data class MyResponse<T>(val header: String,
                     val body: T)
```

I want to write a generic Kotlin function that can deserialise json to various `MyResponse<SimpleBody>` or `MyResponse<ComplexBody>`

```
class JsonSerialiser {   

    val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
    fun <T> fromJson(message: String, classz: Class<T>): T {
        return mapper.readValue(message, classz)
    }
}
val response: MyResponse<SimpleBody> = jsonSerialiser.fromJson("""{"header":"myheader", "body":{"simpleBody":{"name": "A"}}}""", MyResponse::class.java)

data class SimpleBody(val name: String)
```

It failed to compile with this error message

```
Kotlin: Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is MyResponse<*> but MyResponse<SimpleBody> was expected
```

Anyone knows how I can get this to work? I could use MyResponse<*> and then cast it, but I don't feel that's the right way.

Thanks & regards
Tin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need this, just use `com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue`:

```
val response: MyResponse<SimpleBody> = jacksonObjectMapper().readValue("""{"header":"myheader", "body":{"name": "A"}}""")
```

Please note that I changed the json a bit so that Jackson can parse it without further modifications

Comment: I have a generic message listener than can accept any kind of payload, and I want to be able to parse the payload to a generic type and then call appropriate handler s based on the topic mapping. So I don't know if it's `SimpleBody` or not. Can I still achieve that somehow? `override fun messageArrived(topic: String?, message: MqttMessage?) { mapper.readValue<MyResponse<T>>(String(message.payload))}`

Comment: readvalue takes 2 parameters this answer makes no sense